# Append array element only if it is not already there in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, set

I need to add an element to an array only if it is not already there in Javascript.  Basically I'm treating the array as a set.

I need the data to be stored in an array, otherwise I'd just use an object which can be used as a set.

I wrote the following array prototype and wanted to hear if anyone knew of a better way.  This is an O(n) insert.  I was hoping to do O(ln(n)) insert, however, I didn't see an **easy** way to insert an element into a sorted array.  For my applications, the array lengths will be very small, but I'd still prefer something that obeyed accepted rules for good algorithm efficiency:

```
Array.prototype.push_if_not_duplicate = function(new_element){
    for( var i=0; i<this.length; i++ ){
        // Don't add if element is already found
        if( this[i] == new_element ){
            return this.length;
        }
    }
    // add new element
    return this.push(new_element);
}
```

Comment: You say that it is a sorted array, but I don't see how your algorithm enforces any order. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hey Rusty, sort is not enforced for this array because the algorithm checks all elements in the array before insertion.  To insert a unique element at O(ln(n)), the array would have to already be sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you already have a sorted array (if you do not have a sorted array then you can use Array.sort method to sort your data) and now you want to add an element to it if it is not already present in the array. I extracted the **binary insert** (which uses binary search) method in the [google closure library](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_array_array.js.source.html). The relevant code itself would look something like this and it is O(log n) operation because binary search is O(log n).

```
function binaryInsert(array, value) {
  var index = binarySearch(array, value);
  if (index < 0) {
    array.splice(-(index + 1), 0, value);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

function binarySearch(arr, value) {
  var left = 0;  // inclusive
  var right = arr.length;  // exclusive
  var found;
  while (left < right) {
    var middle = (left + right) >> 1;

    var compareResult = value > arr[middle] ? 1 : value < arr[middle] ? -1 : 0;
    if (compareResult > 0) {
      left = middle + 1;
    } else {
      right = middle;
      // We are looking for the lowest index so we can't return immediately.
      found = !compareResult;
    }
  }
  // left is the index if found, or the insertion point otherwise.
  // ~left is a shorthand for -left - 1.
  return found ? left : ~left;
};
```

Usage is binaryInsert(array, value). This also maintains the sort of the array.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a (simple and incomplete) `Set` type before like this:

```
var Set = function (hashCodeGenerator) {
    this.hashCode = hashCodeGenerator;
    this.set = {};
    this.elements = [];
};
Set.prototype = {
  add: function (element) {
    var hashCode = this.hashCode(element);
    if (this.set[hashCode]) return false;
    this.set[hashCode] = true;
    this.elements.push(element);
    return true;
  },
  get: function (element) {
    var hashCode = this.hashCode(element);
    return this.set[hashCode];
  },
  getElements: function () { return this.elements; }
};
```

You just need to find out a good `hashCodeGenerator` function for your objects. If your objects are primitives, this function can return the object itself. You can then access the set elements in array form from the `getElements` accessor. Inserts are O(1). Space requirements are O(2n).

Answer (score 1):

Deleted my other answer because I missed the fact that the array is sorted.

The algorithm you wrote goes through every element in the array and if there are no matches appends the new element on the end. I assume this means you are running another sort after.

The whole algorithm could be improved by using a divide and conquer algorithm. Choose an element in the middle of the array, compare with new element and continue until you find the spot where to insert. It will be slightly faster than your above algorithm, and won't require a sort afterwards.

If you need help working out the algorithm, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is a binary tree, you can insert in O(log n) by putting the new element on the end and bubbling it up into place. Checks for duplicates would also take O(log n) to perform.

[Wikipedia has a great explanation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Arrays)

Comment: Thanks for your response, writing my own bubble algorithm is definitely not something I want to put time into though.

Comment: The algorithm really isn't that bad. Usually, the closer you get to an efficient algorithm, the farther you move away from the obvious, easy to code algorithm. For example, look at a Fibonacci heap vs. a binary heap. The binary heap is easier to code and understand, but the Fibonacci heap has some advantages that you'll never get from the easier solution.

Comment: That's not to say that simpler is never better. It's just that efficient is usually more mathematically complex.

Comment: Hey Rusty, I apologize if I am wrong, but I'm going to guess that you are either in school or recently graduated.  One thing they don't teach you in college is that in a production environment, its usually a very bad idea to implement algorithms from scratch.  There are two very good reasons for this 1) TIME -You can get far more done with your time if you use previously existing code. 2) ERRORS - Writing algorithms from scratch carries a risk of having bugs in it.  Using tried and true code minimizes this risk.

Comment: Ha, I hope you didn't misunderstand and think that I would encourage someone to implement their own Fibonacci heap. That, as you say, is a waste.